# Arduino Uno Upload Fails

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have received an arduino uno and some code for it as part of a project I am working on. I have never worked with them before so this is a completely new experience for me.

I am using the Arduino application from their website and when I compile the code it works fine. When I upload however I get the error:

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x41
```

I have looked at every single google result returned for this and I haven't gotten anywhere. I have tried uploading on 3 different machines with a minimum of two different operating systems on each machine. How on earth do I get it to accept this code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RX and TX pins should be disconnected during programming the device. Check this.

Comment: Well I'll be damned... A week of this and not once did I think of that. Thanks!