# Arduino - UNO R3.2 can't upload from IDE

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

New to Arduino, I've built [this keyestudio](http://www.keyestudio.com/wp/2016/05/ks0071/) (mini tank robot) kit. I'm trying to upload my first sketch to the board. Verification goes fine, however the upload process fails with the following message:

```
Sketch uses 5340 bytes (16%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 291 bytes (14%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1757 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
```

- Using mac 10.11.6 OS X El Capitan
- I've tried to upload both with the online and native IDE.
- I've followed [this article](https://learn.sparkfun.com/ftdiDriversMac) to try and update my drivers.
- [image]

**Update**
Pictures of the board & chip:
[image: board]
[image]

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: An original Arduino Uno uses an ATmega16U2 for USB-to-serial connection not a FTDI chip. And Chinese copies might use CH340.

Comment: How can I know if mine is an original?

Comment: The different chip can be a good attention point. Se the image below where indicates the chip position in board (upper right). Look with magnifying glasses in your board. Image is here: http://ik.imagekit.io/industrybuying/c/tr:n-pdp_sec_product_img_thumb/products/electronics-robotics/arduino-boards-and-accessories/arduino-accessories/EL.AR.AR.1571415_1.jpg

Comment: If it says it's an Arduino on the board, it could be an original or a [counterfeit](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Products/Counterfeit). If it doesn't it's just a copy. But that doesn't tell us what USB-to-serial chip it has. You will have to look at the board yourself.

Comment: I've added some photos, so... What driver should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a hint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056166/arduino-uno-upload-fails) stating that the

> RX and TX pins should be disconnected

So I tried uploading to the board while it is not connected to any other shield and it worked fine.